# Objective-C event-driven HTML parsing

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parsing

I need to be able to parse HTML snippets in an event-driven way. For example, if the parser finds a HTML tag, it should notify me and pass the HTML tag, value, attributes etc. to a delegate. I cannot use `NSXMLParser` because I have messy HTML. Is there a useful library for that?

What I want to do is parse the HTML and create a `NSAttributedArray` and display it in a `UITextView`.

Comment: Try rexeg in an own created class with your own created delegate

Comment: Do not have time for implementing that. I need a fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

YES you can parse HTML content of file.

If you want to get specific value from `HTML` content you need to **Parce** `HTML` content by using [`Hpple`](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple). Also This is [documentation with exmple](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)  that are is for parse `HTML`. Another way is **rexeg** but it is more complicated so this is best way in your case.